# subprocess popen function get lock when calling it with muscle or mafft in a pipeline

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to include sequence alignment using muscle or mafft, depending of the user in a pipeline.
To do so, i'm using the `subprocess` package, but sometimes, the subprocess never terminates and my script doesn't continue. Here is how I call the subprocess:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(str(muscle_cline), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
child.wait()
```

The command `muscle_cline` looks like this:

```
./tools/muscle/muscle5.1.win64.exe -align C:\Users\alexis\Desktop\git-repo\MitoSplitter\results\genes-fasta\12S_tmp.fasta -output C:\Users\alexis\Desktop\git-repo\MitoSplitter\results\alignement\12S_tmp_muscle_align.fasta
```

I'm calling this line in a function that just creates the command line and calls the subprocess, and converts the output.

I'm then calling this function in a `for` loop

```
for file in getFastaFile(my_dir):
    alignSequenceWithMuscle(file)
```

The issue is that sometimes, for unknown reasons, the subprocess never finishes and get locked...

I tried to check the returncode of the child, or print stuff to see where it gets locked, and it's getting locked when I'm calling the subprocess.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is all rather vague. What's the type of `muscle_cline` if it's not already a `str`? Does it help if you use `subprocess.check_output` instead of the `Popen` + `wait` dance? You don't seem to be doing anything with the `subprocess.PIPE`s so that's probably where it's blocking.

Comment: Using `PIPE` with `.wait()` can cause deadlock, use `.communicate()` instead, or better yet `subprocess.check_output` or `subprocess.run` instead. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally want to avoid bare `Popen`, especially if you don't have a good understanding of its requirements. This is precisely why Python offers you `subprocess.check_output` and other higher-level functions which take care of the nitty-gritty of managing a subprocess.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(
    ["./tools/muscle/muscle5.1.win64.exe",
     "-align", r"C:\Users\alexis\Desktop\git-repo\MitoSplitter\results\genes-fasta\12S_tmp.fasta",
     "-output", r"C:\Users\alexis\Desktop\git-repo\MitoSplitter\results\alignement\12S_tmp_muscle_align.fasta"],
    text=True)
```

Notice also the raw strings `r"..."` to avoid having to double the backslashes, and the `text=True` keyword argument to instruct Python to implicitly decode the `bytes` you receive from the subprocess.